# Java connect with JDBC to Postgres - SQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Iam tryig to connect to a Postgres Database. Iam really new to that and have read a post in the forum. But I didn't manage it.

```
public void connect() {
    //Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", user);
        props.setProperty("password", password);
        props.setProperty("ssl","true");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        //String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
        //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Erfolgreich verbunden!");
    }
    catch (Exception  e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I updated my Code.
The database is deployed to heroku.
It throws the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://vuqmbekwlgohkw:******
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
at com.company.Database.connect(Database.java:20) p
at com.company.Main.start(Main.java:16)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://vuqmbekwlgohkw:***************
```

Comment: `InitialContext` and look ups by JNDI name is for Application Servers (JEE technology) if you are not developing an JEE application you should simply follow the JDBC connection examples like here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html

Comment: Thank you but this leads to the error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres.

Comment: Uncomment the `Class.forName` line. You have to refer to the PostgreSQL driver class somewhere in order to give the JVM a reason to load it. Once loaded, it will register itself as the driver for a `jdbc:postgres` connection string.

Comment: I uncommented Class.forName but I still get the error that java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn That line of code hasn't been needed since 2007.

Comment: The code you have now posted does not throw this exception. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://vuqmbekwlgohkw:******
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
 at com.company.Database.connect(Database.java:20)
 at com.company.Main.start(Main.java:16)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://vuqmbekwlgohkw:***************

So it throws this exception... and now?

Comment: Only you think that `NoInitialContextException` and `SQLException` are the same thing, which they aren't.

Comment: @user207421 oh you talking about the name of this question. I will change that. Maybe you just try to say that a bit more friendly to inexperienced members next time.

Comment: I treat everybody the same here.

Comment: doesn't necessarily make it better. I changed the name! :)
any idea why it isn´t working? would be nice if you change the down vote after i fixed that...

Comment: @user207421 you're right about `Class.forName`. It's been a while since I configured a JDBC source in code!

Comment: @F4ll0ut I get the "no suitable driver" exception not just when the driver isn't on the classpath but also when the URL is malformed. If I use the commented-out `url` value you have, it tries to connect. But if I try something like the URL that actually appears in your error message ("vuqmebek...") then I get "no suitable driver" even if the driver is available.

Comment: What is the actual value of `url` you're using and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that your connection URL is malformed.

When `DriverManager.getConnection` throws SQLException, the message includes the exact `url` value passed to the function. In your case, that looks like `jdbc:postgres://vuqmbekwlgohkw:******`.

But obviously that is not the URL you are using. You have replaced part of the URL with asterisks. That suggests that you think the format of the URL is:

`jdbc:postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname`

which seems to be what Heroku provides in the DATABASE_URL environment variable. You are using asterisks to prevent us from seeing the password.

However, it looks like the PostgreSQL JDBC driver does not accept URLs in this format. When I tried, I also got the "No suitable driver" error. [According to the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), the format of the URL is:

`jdbc:postgres://host:port/database`

Some parts are optional, but the driver does not appear to support putting the user name or password in the URL.

I was able to connect to an AWS PostgreSQL instance by using the URL format described in the documentation and using the connection properties to set the user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are new so I'm gonna start with the painfully obvious, do you have the driver on your classpath?

it's a jar you add to your project that you can download from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Otherwise I have an example of the url that worked for me, except I was not exactly using jdbc, it was a spring-boot project:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-174-99-88-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/asdfasdfsadf?sslmode=require
```

There is no port number in your commented URL and not all parameters might be supported, like Willis pointed out.

Comment: I think he has the driver on his classpath, because he reported that adding the Class.forName did nothing. If the driver wasn’t on the the classpath then trying to get a reference to it would have thrown an exception.